# Should I add a insert_time column for tracking the sequence [sqlite]

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with an auto-increment primary key column; I want to fetch the items of this table order by the time when the record is inserted. I wonder is it necessary to have a dedicated insert_time column for that purpose?

Comment: See the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know which records came before others you can just use the primary key. If you want to know the actual **time** of the record, you will need another column.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add insert_time column. You can order your data with auto-increment column. Last inserted row have max number.